# Boundaries missing in merged table

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have tried to merge this table with mine in order to get school district boundaries and have so far been unsuccessful. I can successfully merge the data by school district but can not see the boundaries once the data sets are merged. What am I doing wrong?

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=18zoNXzPRfPCPAK66GAdlwWg3c2vLeoGsxuSt91g#rows:id=1

Comment: Which is the other table? Can you provide both tables or at least the merged table, otherwise it's hard to understand what is not working here.

Comment: How are you trying to do the merge? The "name" column in the table seems to contain the KML data, the description is formatted with HTML, what key are you using for the merge?